# Parsing of ひっそりとはしておらず

Tags: grammar, particle-は, negation, scope

> 秋ほどひっそりとはしておらず、冬よりは華やかではない、可憐な夜空。

[current subject is the spring sky]

*(the spring sky) is not quiet to the degree the fall (sky) is, ...*

I was told that if you have an adv-to and want a noun describing/sentence ending phrase, you add the generic verb する. Can you just stick a は in the middle of that?

秋ほどひっそりと(contrastive は)しておらず ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that the は is the contrastive は. Here it indicates the scope of negation. In other words, the ～～と**は**していない is 部分否定(partial negation), not 全否定(total negation).

Here it negates *秋ほど*ひっそりとしている, not just ひっそりとしている.

秋ほどひっそりと**は**しておらず -- partial negation "Not so quiet as autumn"
ひっそりとしておらず -- total negation "not quiet"

Answer (score 1):

> I was told that if you have an adv-to and want a noun describing/sentence ending phrase, you add the generic verb する.

Sure, you can do that.
ひっそりと生活{せいかつ}する。
のんびりと散歩{さんぽ}する。
と is optional. (I feel this と adds somewhat explanatory sense as の does.)

Simpler verbs can be also used this way: ひっそりと暮{く}らす, のんびりと歩{ある}く, ひっそりとする, のんびりとする.（Again, と is optional.）

> Can you just stick a は in the middle of that?
>   秋ほどひっそりと(contrastive は)しておらず ?

I feel the negative expression requires the は. It's just to add a slight bit of the sense of emphasis though, it's surely smoother with は.
ひっそりとは生活しておらず、
ひっそりとは暮らしておらず、
ひっそりとはしておらず、